# What does this picture and pattern mean?

Tags: game-identification

I am trying to find out what this picture means and where to find it (I could not locate the source). It's really important for me. Thanks everyone for helping.

[image: What does this picture mean? Where to find it?]

Comment: Are we sure this is a game identification question, and not a "how do I solve this puzzle" one, since it was migrated from [puzzling.se]?

Answer (score 4):

It's from a mobile game called [Monument Valley](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/monument-valley/id728293409).

Source: Google reverse image search